# Deleting an attachment created with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, paperclip, attachment

I have a Rails app with a Post model that uses Paperclip to upload photos. I want to be able to delete a photo from a post when I'm in that post's `edit` view. The following code deletes an image from a post, but now I cannot create new attachments (to new or existing posts):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :photo
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  attr_accessor :delete_photo
  before_save :delete_photo, if: ->{ delete_photo == '1' && !photo.dirty? }

  private
  def delete_photo
    self.photo = nil
  end
end
```

and in `views/posts/edit.html.erb`:

```
  <fieldset>
    <ol class="post-fields-list">
      <li>
        <%= f.label :title %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= f.label :body %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </li>
      <li><%= f.file_field :photo %></li>
      <li>
        <%= f.label :delete_image %><br />
        <%= f.check_box :delete_photo %>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
```

The last element in the above list is where the checkbox for deleting images is created.

As mentioned, when I comment out this line in the model:

```
  before_save :delete_photo, if: ->{ delete_photo == '1' && !photo.dirty? }
```

I can create attachments no problem.

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE:**

I've noticed that the HTML generated by `f.check_box` looks rather weird:

```
<input name="post[delete_photo]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="post_delete_photo" name="post[delete_photo]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
has_attached_file :photo
attr_accessor :delete_photo
before_validation { photo.clear if delete_photo == '1' }
```

No need to destroy asset, Paperclip will do it.

In the form form.check_box(:delete_asset) will suffice.

Comment: simple! i like this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `attr_accessor :delete_photo` attribute accessor for delete photo try create your own getter and setter method for delete_photo.
use `clear` method to remove attachment instead of assigning `nil`.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :photo
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  before_save :delete_photo

  def delete_photo
    @delete_photo ||= "0"
  end

  def delete_photo=(value)
    @delete_photo = value
  end

  private
    def delete_photo
      self.photo.clear = nil if @delete_photo == '1' && !self.photo.dirty?
    end
end
```

Comment: Just tried this, but it doesn't work... btw, the images are being saved to disk in the `/public` folder.